# Count multiple Columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to count the occurrence of IDs in 3 different columns using SQL. The raw table would look like:

```
id | A  | B  | C
------------------
1  | A1 | B1 | C1
2  | A1 | B2 | C1
3  | A1 | B1 | C2
4  | A2 | B1 | C2
5  | A1 | B2 | C2
```

The desired Table should look like:

```
id | A  | count(A) | B  | count(B) | C  | count(C)
--------------------------------------------------
1  | A1 | 4        | B1 | 3        | C1 | 2
2  | A1 | 4        | B2 | 2        | C1 | 2
3  | A1 | 4        | B1 | 3        | C2 | 3
4  | A2 | 1        | B1 | 3        | C2 | 3
5  | A1 | 4        | B2 | 2        | C2 | 3
```

I tried the below query for a single column but didn't quite get the desired results:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(A) from table_name GROUP BY A;
```

But am unable to do the same for 3 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COUNT` as analytic function:

```
SELECT
    id,
    A,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A) cnt_A,
    B,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY B) cnt_B,
    C,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C) cnt_C
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

You don't want `GROUP BY` here, at least not by itself, because that aggregates the original records all of which you want to include in the output.